# Salesforce classic homepage branding

Tags: classic, home-page-layout, theme-branding

We are adding brand logo and header background colour to classic applications. I am able to do it for console applications. The issue is on the default homepage as it just shows the brand logo but not the background colour. Wanted to confirm if this is the standard behaviour and cannot be changed or am I missing something here.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Looks like there is no standard setting to change background color in classic unlike in lightning which has the [themes](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.brand_your_org_in_lightning_experience.htm&type=5). Alternate would be to use custom Visualforce page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard setting to change background color in Salesforce classic. For custom apps, Salesforce offers you to only change the logo image.

See bob_buzzard's response on [related post](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AfYAIA0). An alternative would be to use a custom Visualforce page.

Incase of lightning, we have out the box [themes](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.brand_your_org_in_lightning_experience.htm&type=5) provided.